# struts2 action double submission

Tags: struts2

I have struts2 action method. It will be called from different server. i.e. In our applciation we are integrating the icici Payment gateway. My action method will be called from icici server. In that method i am performing some logic. Based on logic it will be redirected to some other action.

```
<action name="iciciResponse" class="com.yatrasoft.yatratravel.agent.b2c.PaymentGateWayAction" method="iciciResponse">
<result name="buybusTicket" type="redirect">/tentativeBusbooking.action?searchKey=${getSearchKey()}</result>
</action>
```

My booking logic is present in **tentativeBusbooking()** .After executing this method the result will be displayed to the end-user. Now browser URL will be like this.

```
http://192.168.0.94:8080/travelyatra/tentativeBusbooking.action?searchKey=NDIwMTMzMDR8MTQ5OTA4MjF8bnVsbHxudWxsfG51bGx8bnVsbHxudWxsfG51bGx8bnVsbHxudWxsfHxud
```

But the problem is, if the user refresh the browser, the **tentativeBusbooking()** is getting executed once again.

If i have JSP page, by using the **s:token** we can avoid the double form submission. But my action is called directly from the other server. So, How to avoid the double submission in this scenario.

If i need to write my own logic for this,can u help me. I am trainee s/w engineer(5 months experience only)...

Comment: We are integrating nearly 10 payment gateways. Here i said ICICI. We have to handle the above scenario in all the payment gateways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to do a redirectAction after tentativeBusbooking(). In this scenario, instead of returning SUCCESS, you would return a result such as "bookingComplete" with a result type of redirectAction.

The result would be a display only jsp and if the page is refreshed, only the results would be displayed, not the original submission.

For example:

```
@Results({
@Result(name = "success", location = "/WEB-INF/content/tentativeBusbooking.jsp"),
@Result(name = "bookingComplete", type="redirectAction" location = "booking")})
public class BoxController extends ActionSupport{

    public void execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void tentativeBusbooking(){
        //Do stuff...
        return "bookingComplete";
    }
```

In the annotated example above, the bookingComplete result would result type would redirect the action back onto itself after the tentativeBusbooking() calling the execute() rather than the tentativeBusbooking() again when refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

IN General and most standard way page refresh at the time of payment capture is not at all suggested and in most cases payment gateway tend to give warning to the user not to double click.refresh the browser as it will invalidate the payment.

In almost all such cases transaction will always end up in invalid mode.More over to handle such use-case it is more of responsibility of payment gateway and not your application.

I suggest you to have a look at ICICI payseal integration doc if they have any mechanism to handle this double submission problem or not?

Comment: It's not the issue with ICICI. It's our application issue. Because we are redirecting to some other action based on my application logic.. and we need to redirect to more than 4 results based on the logic. Here i have shown only tentativeBusBookig(). In actually we have 4 results.

Comment: than u need to send similar token as used by <s:token> to check for duplicate request

Comment: i am unable to understand where to add <s:token>. If u don't mine explain little clear.

Comment: i mean to say you need to mimic same flow as being created by <s:token> and its interceptor, since you can not use <s:token> so you need to have same functionality for your flow

Comment: i am trainee s/w engineer(5 months experience only). can u help me in this.

Comment: @Eswar: hers is the source code of SessionTokenInterceptor http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.2.1/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/TokenInterceptor.java just have a look how it is doing the things